# JQuery AJAX post not working if more than 1 function is defined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a JQUERY AJAX post function that will work if there is one function, but if I try and include another function in addition, the second function does not post through to the .PHP script. I am a beginner in JQUERY but have tried every variation, but it will process the first function, but if I add any other functions, will not process those.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function toggle[My CSS code](x) {
    if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
        $('#'+x).slideDown(400);
    } else {
        $('#'+x).hide();
    }
    $('.[My CSS Code]').hide();
}
function add(a,b){
var URL="process.php";
$("#add").text("Processing").show();
$.post(URL,{request:"request",mem1:a,mem2:b,},function(data){
$("#add").html(data).show().fadeOut(12000);
});
}
/////This is where the code stops working and the .php script doesnt work//////////

function accept (x) {
    var URL="process.php";
$.post(URL,{ request: "accept", reqID: x, } ,function(data) {
        $("#req"+requestID).html('<font color="#000">Accepted</font>').show();
});
}
function deny (x) {
    var URL="process.php";
$.post(URL,{ request: "deny", reqID: x, } ,function(data) {
       $("#req"+x).html('denied').show();
});
}
</script>
```

So it will process the add function but not the accept nor deny function via the URL posted in the add. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `$("#add").html(data).show().fadeOut(12000)` should end with `;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only defining the URL in the first function, and it's var'ed so the other functions don't have access and have an undefined url

Comment: I noticed that, but unfortunately defining the location URL's still nothing happens.

Comment: it should work, I'd have to see where these functions are being called and how the php is set up to help troubleshoot much more

Comment: also "requestID" in your accept function should probably be "x"

Comment: Like usual, it was something simple that I was overlooking. It was the reference to ("x") Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browser you are using the trailing comma in your ajax options object may be causing a problem:

```
//                                  this little guy
//                                         |
//                                         v
$.post(URL,{request:"request",mem1:a,mem2:b,},function(data){
```

I have known IE to choke on trailing commas in object or array definitions, though FF and Chrome usually seem to be able to handle it

Comment: Thanks for the input! If I programmed in IE I probably would've seeked the help of a professional therapist. Thank you for taking a look though!

Comment: Haha, no problem, I know the feeling too.  Glad you found your bug.